# We want to use the Rocket.chat with our own server instead of open.rocket.chat some how we are not able to go ahead

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, websocket, rocket.chat

We want to use Rocket.chat app with our server (domain) instead of open.rocket.chat, but when we replaced the open.rocket.chat with our server URL we are getting the error as below...

```
[WebSocket] did disconnect with error (Optional(Error Domain=WebSocket Code=400 "Invalid HTTP upgrade" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid HTTP upgrade})) 
Socket will send message: { 
"id" : "0tZIJpxo2ifrm4q18OnFpQfvYQA0OmqS1OyD3kKLFQvme3G4er", 
"method" : "public-settings\/get", 
"msg" : "method" 
}
```

Actually we have done all the server set up as per the guidelines of Rocket.chat forum.

I googled a lot for this issue but some how the google seems to be pretty thin about it.

Is anyone from rocket chat or from all around will help me to trace the issue, Your any help will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you specify what version of the app are you using, and what version of the server are you using? Also, make sure that your server support WebSocket connection. There's a warning on the repository about that:

> Make sure your server supports WebSocket. These are the minimum requirements for Apache 2.4 and Nginx 1.3 or greater.

You can read more information here: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.iOS

There's also a few issues from other users discussing about app connectivity.

Comment: Thanks Rafael for your valuable time, I am not able to get the app version, but we have downloaded the clone from https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.iOS this thread, and the server version is "Centos 7" , will you please help me with, whether we do have some set up on iOS side if we want to use our own server/domain instead of rocket.chat's server, And which kind of setting we do need to do on our server to make it work.. Your help will be highly appreciated because we are struggling on same issue from last 3 days...

Comment: Hi @Rafael Kellermann Streit : Actually we connected with our domain, but facing weird issue, that, sometimes we are able to connect to server instantly but most of the times we fails to connect to our server, without any error, We cross checked everything from front end and also from back end (server side), As the same URL connects instantly when we are connecting it from web app, but this issue is there from mobile app only... will you please share your ideas over the same, your any help will be highly appreciated.